# Adivinar numero con Java con bucle while y con intentos

Tags: java, while

He hecho este programa con Java, que el usuario tiene que adivinar el numero con 5 intentos, el numero es 6, pero al segundo intento se cuelga

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practica15 {

    public static final int NUMERO_SECRETO = 6;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int num=0;
        int intentos=5;

        Scanner teclado= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Introduce un numero");
        num=teclado.nextInt();

        if (num==NUMERO_SECRETO && intentos<=5) {
            System.out.println("El numero es correcto");
        }

        while (num != NUMERO_SECRETO && intentos >= 1) {
            intentos--;
            System.out.println("Error, el numero no es correcto, te quedan: " +
                intentos + " intentos ");
            teclado.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Introduce el numero de nuevo");

            num=teclado.nextInt();

            teclado.close();
            if (num==NUMERO_SECRETO && intentos <5) {
                System.out.println("Correcto. Lo has conseguido en " + 
                    intentos + " intentos");
            }else if (num!=NUMERO_SECRETO && intentos==1) {
                System.out.println("Has agotado los intentos");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola Marxal. Puedes explicar mejor los pasos para reproducir el problema?  Has probado el modo debug para ejecutar instruccion a instruccion y ver las condiciones que se estan aplicando ?

Comment: Ya te han respondido a la pregunta correctamente, aún así te comento (no sé si lo has dado ya), pero intenta hacer el código con un do-while, te quedaría más limpio y está mejor planteado. Saludos!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que cierras el Scanner, borrando la linea `teclado.close();` debería funcionar perfecto.

Espero que te ayude, un saludo.

```
    run:
Introduce un numero
3
Error, el numero no es correcto, te quedan: 4 intentos 
Introduce el numero de nuevo
5
Error, el numero no es correcto, te quedan: 3 intentos 
Introduce el numero de nuevo
6
Correcto. Lo has conseguido en 3 intentos
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)
```

Comment: Así si, ahora lo entiendo, al cerrar el teclado, se salía del bucle y no lo volvía a pedir y causaba un error.

Comment: @marxal si te ha servido recuerda marcarla como aceptada. Un saludo

Answer (score -1):

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Adivinar {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
  Scanner ingreso = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  final int numeroSecreto = 6;
  int numero=0;
  int intentos = 10;
  int intentos2 = 0;

  do {
  
  System.out.println("Ingrese un numero: ");
  numero = ingreso.nextInt();
  if(numero == numeroSecreto) {
      System.out.println("Felicidades, el numero secreto es " + numeroSecreto +",acabas de adivinar el numero luego de " + (intentos2 + 1)+ " intentos.");
      break;
      
  } else if(numero!=numeroSecreto) {
      System.out.println("Numero incorrecto,vuelva a intentarlo.");
      intentos--;
      System.out.println("Te quedan "+intentos+ " intentos");
      intentos2 = intentos2 + 1;
  }
      System.out.println("");
      if(intentos == 0) {
          System.out.println("Se acabaron los intentos, gracias por particiár de nuestro juego.");
      }
  
} while(intentos>0 && intentos<10);
```

}
}

Comment: Hola leandro, bienvenido,gracias por tu respuesta, mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada, por otro lado, fijate que estás contestando una pregunta hecha hace... 5 años ;)